# Como da loop em células selecionadas no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quando eu clico e arrasto para baixo as células seguintes na devida imagem, na célula "E21" aparece um '3' decorrente do acompanhamento da sequencia de células da "A15" até "A18" como eu faço para dar um loop apenas nas células de "A15" até "A17"? para o resultado sair "aguardando" ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o que você quer dizer com *"dar um loop"*?

Comment: Eu quis dizer, a função repetir as células A15 até A17, para o resultado da "aguardando", pois todo vez que eu clico e arrasto esse bendito '3' aparece, referente a célula A18

Comment: bom só vai dar problema ao arrastar para copiar a fórmula se tiver algum problema nas referências. Podo mostrar como está a fórmula na célula "E18"?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver! vou responder minha pergunta. Ficou uma fórmula bem grande

Comment: como a tabela é fixa, ao copiar a fórmula muda as linhas, precisa usar `A$15:A$17`, basta colocar o `$` para que não mude as linhas ao copiar a fórmula

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fixando as células correspondentes A15 até A17 e adicionando uma função "Se" na A18 até C18, dizendo que se for diferente das numerações de 1 até 3 e fixando esses valores, chame a célula "incorreto" caso adicione algum numero fora da sequencia de 1,2,3.